# Android app test using selenium webdriver

Tags: android, selenium, automation, webdriver, appium

I want to test android app using selenium webdriver. I don't have source code. I have only apk file.

**Question:**

1. Is it possible to record the test steps and run it using selenium
   webdriver?
2. Is it possible to test a android app using apk file and
   selenium webdriver?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at [Appium](http://appium.io/) if Selenium is what's most familiar to you. Appium allows you to use Selenium client libraries to automate Android apps.

Comment: what about selendroid ?

Answer (score 4):

You have an `APK` file, therefore I'm going to assume you are trying to automate tests against an actual *native* Android application.

If so, Selenium is not what you want to be using. It is a *web* application automated testing framework. It isn't going to work with *native* applications.

Robotium, is probably the best one to be using for this:

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/

Set it up, come back and post a **new** question if you have any issues.